# Microsoft SQL AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, alwayson

Is it possible to determine to which endpoint a client is connecting to. 
i.e. SQL Availability Group Listener endpoint or the SQL Instance itself.

The Problem I'm facing is simple. I've recently started setting up Always On in my environment (80+ SQL Servers). I need to determine which client connections are still incorrectly configured to use the SQL Instance instead of the HA Listener.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using `local_net_address` the query below, taken from http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2013/08/how-to-tell-if-your-users-are.html might be helpful. The IP shown as `local_net_address` should be the IP of the listener, not the server.

```
SELECT
    ec.session_id,
    es.host_name,
    es.program_name,
    local_net_address,
    local_tcp_port
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections ec
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions es ON ec.session_id = es.session_id;
GO
```